# How do Generics and Fields assist DAO Pattern in Standalone Java applications

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, dao, dto

```
//Interface DAO

    public abstract class BaseDAO<T extends BaseDTO> {


    public void update(T t) throws DBException {
     Field[] fieldsToInsert = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    //code to update database object academic or event
    }

     public Integer create(T t) throws DBException {
      Field[] fieldsToInsert = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    //code to create academic or event in database
    }

} 



//Concrete DAOs
public class AcademicDAO extends BaseDAO<AcademicDTO> {
//provide implementation
}

public class EventDAO extends BaseDAO<EventDTO> {
//provide implementation
}



//Transfer object
public class AcademicDTO extends BaseDTO {
   String title;
   String surname;
   //getters and setters
}


public class BaseDTO {

    protected Integer ID;

    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

Hello Guys, I have a sample code on me that follows the above structure to create a small java application to manage academics and events. It is leniently following this [pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)

1- You experts are familiar with this pattern more than me. I would like to understand why generics are used in this case so DAOs can extend and implement a generic base class. It would be great if one can show how generics here may be advantageous using an example.

2 - I have also witnessed the use of java Fields. Is there a link between generics and Fields?

I would like to document DAO pattern in an academic report, but I am finding difficult to understand how *Generics* and *Reflect Field* play a part here. Do they support flexibility and loose coupling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided is reusable set of logic to load and persist entities.  Many times, in an application of non-trivial size, you'll wind up persisting many different types of objects.  In this example, you can define as many objects as necessary, but only define the logic to actually save and load once.  By asking the DTO what `Field` objects are there, it can get at the data to help construct queries for loading and saving.

Generics allow you to use this pattern while maintaining type safety.  `AcademicDAO` can only handle `AcadmeicDTO`.  You can't use `AcademicDAO` to store `EventDTO`.  Generics allow the instance of the class to rely on a more specific type when dealing with the `Field` objects.  If you didn't have generics, the `BaseDAO` would take `Object`, and you wouldn't be able to access any methods except those that Object provides because the JVM wouldn't know what class is provided, so it has to limit it's knowledge to that of `Object`.  Using `getClass().getDeclaredFields()` bypasses that limitation because `getClass()` returns the actual class of the `Object` parameter.

`Field` is just a way to use reflection to access the values of the properties in each DTO.  If you had to access the fields directly, with `getTitle()`, you couldn't reuse a generic base class to do your persistence.  What would happen when you needed to access EventDTO?  You would have to provide logic for that.  `Field` allows you to skip that logic.

**Edit:**

To explain what I mean by accessing `getID`, you could do the following within `BaseDAO` because `T` is known to be a `BaseDTO` with a `getID()` method defined:

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<T extends BaseDTO> {

    public boolean update(T t) throws DBException {
        Integer id = t.getID();
        Field[] fields = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        // Assuming you have a db object to execute queries using bind variables:
        boolean success = db.execute("UPDATE table SET ... WHERE id = ?", id.intValue());
        return success;
    }
}
```

If you had this instead (in a non-generic class):

```
public boolean update(Object o) throws DBException {
    // This line doesn't work, since Object doesn't have a getID() method.
    Integer id = t.getID();
    Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    boolean success = db.execute("UPDATE table SET ... WHERE id = ?", id.intValue());
    return success;
}
```

You'd have to look through those `Field` objects, or ask for the ID field and assume it existed.

Comment: this is very clearly explained and easy to understood. Many thanks.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on the following line please :

If you didn't have generics, the BaseDAO would take Object, and you wouldn't be able to access any Field except those that Object provides because the JVM wouldn't know what class is provided, so it has to limit it's knowledge to that of Object

Comment: Actually, that part was incorrect.  The `getClass()` call returns the actual type, and `getDeclaredFields()` then returns all fields declared on that type, but not its inherited fields.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Steve this part "If you didn't have generics, the BaseDAO would take Object, and you wouldn't be able to access any methods except those that Object provides because the JVM wouldn't know what class is provided, so it has to limit it's knowledge to that of Object." Is not clear to me.  I understand the role of getclass() and so on, but what if we didnt use generics in terms of BaseDao is confusing from you answer.

Comment: The JVM can only work with the types that have been declared.  If I had a method `save(Object o)`, and I passed in a `BaseDTO`, that method could not access the `getID()` method on `BaseDTO`.  The input parameter is an `Object`, which doesn't have `getID()` defined.  Does that help?

Comment: so because the save is accepting parameter T it has the freedom to accept getid() method?. You've lost me with getID method. Can you please edit answer and demonstrate with an example?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1.  The use of generics allows the same implementations of `update` and `create` to be used regardless of the type of the DTO. Consider if you didn't use generics. Then the best you could do for the parameter type of `update` would be `BaseDTO`, but then you could call

```
academicDAO.update( eventDTO )
```

which doesn't make sense.  With the code as you have it, this would be a type error.  So the main advantage is: better type checking.

For question 2. The use of Fields allows a single implementation of `update` and `create` to work on DTO object of various concrete types.